# Как правильно инициализировать RecyclerView во фрагменте ViewPager

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Я использую `String[] array`, который хранится в `array.xml`. Из этого массива строк я формирую объекты, которые используются для `RecyclerView`, который в свою очередь находится во `Фрагменте`, который находится во `ViewPager`. Так вот, когда дело доходит до свайпа вправо то анимация передвижения происходит с торможением (рывком). Мой вопрос, как правильно инициализировать RecyclerView, чтобы UI не подтормаживал при свайпе. Всего 35 тегов в массиве.

Мой код из `Фрагмента:`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_prop2, container, false);
    fragmentLayout = (ConstraintLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentLayout);

    initTags();
    initRecyclerView();

    return rootView;
}
```

Метод `initTags()`:

```
public void initTags(){
    String[] tagsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tags_array);
    for (int i = 0; i < tagsArray.length; i++) {
        tags.add(new Tag(tagsArray[i], false, false));
    }
}
```

Comment: А что у вас в initRecyclerView() и почему он вызывается дважды? А вообще, если там ничего особенного (шрифтов, картинок и т.п.), заполняйте массив при старте активности и передавайте его в рециклер при показе.

Comment: Поправил initRecyclerView() - вызывается один раз. Там ничего особенного. Попробую при стате. Но если бы там были шрифты и картинки, то как действовать лучшим образом?

Comment: Кэшировать, чтобы шрифт и картинки не подгружались каждый раз из ресов. Если не поможет, покажите все-таки `initRecyclerView`  и xml разметки.

Answer (score 1):

**Решил проблему** с помощью метода: `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit);`

Метод позволяет указать к-во фрагментов, которые должны храниться в памяти при инициализации ViewPager. Вот хорошая статья по этому вопросу:
https://techcodegeek.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/android-viewpager-and-performance-improvements/